# how to prevent opening some activities after the first run of the application?

Tags: android, android-studio

> knowing that I use buttons to move from activity to another
>
> > PS I am new in android so be kind

```
public class swipe2 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener 

private   Button next,skip;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.swipe2);
    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next2);
    skip=(Button) findViewById(R.id.skip2);
    next.setOnClickListener(swipe2.this);
    skip.setOnClickListener(swipe2.this);
}
```

> I use this buttons here

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(v==next)
    {
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(swipe2.this, swipe3.class);
        startActivity(homeIntent);
        finish();
    }

    else
    {
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(swipe2.this, lastswipe.class);
        startActivity(homeIntent);
        finish();
    }

}
```

So what should I do in order to solve?

Comment: You did not specify an error.

Comment: there is no error i just want to know the way to set some activities to be shown on the first run only

Answer (score 1):

you can use [shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Make another Activity call it **StarterActivity.java**

inside onCreate add these lines;

```
     if(isFirstTime()){
          //start the activity you want to have for the first run only
         }  
    else
         {

 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_ NAME, 
        MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("first_time", false);
        editor.apply();
         //start your main activity here
     }

private boolean isFirstTime(){
      SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_
      NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
      boolean firstTime= prefs.getBoolean("first_time", true);
       return firstTime;
}
```

Dont forget to add it to the manefist and make it a launcher activity.

Comment: i found this error in [MY_PREFS_NAME] what should i do !         
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_ NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit(); @ El-bishoy

Comment: `MY_PREFS_ NAME` assign a value to it is just a string. MODE_PRIVATE  is an integer of value = 0